# Populating crystal report viewer database login prompt with vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

My current vb.net code only seems to be populating the username field in crystal report viewer database login prompt but the password field remains blank.

```
Dim view As New CrystalReport1

Dim username As String = "cdruser"

Dim password As String = "cdruser10"

View.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password)
```

Result:

[image: my code result]

Comment: @ovaltein please help, you helped me greatly before.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim info As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
info = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()

Dim currentDB As String = ' Your Database location
info.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ""
info.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = currentDB
info.ConnectionInfo.Password = ""
info.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ""

For Each t As Table In cReport.Database.Tables
     t.ApplyLogOnInfo(info)
Next
```

This is the code I always use when connecting to Crystal Reports files.

Comment: Let me know if there are any issues, if it works, be sure to upvote/accept it as the answer.